# Configuring SQL Server to automatically take database snapshot and use that instead of actual database

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, snapshot, database-administration

I have been allocated task of fetching data from database. However, as per   requirement, I can't update parts of fetched data which are continuously updated in the database.

In other words, I just need to provide data instance up to a specific point in time. So I figured I could take snapshot of database and use that to show   data to client which will always be consistent in the sense that updated records in actual database won't be reflected. What I exactly need is to take automatic snapshot for example after every hour, and then read from that. Is it possible in SQL Server? In Oracle I done same using `RMAN`, but I am lost in SQL Server.

Comment: Just take a database snapshot every hour using SQL Server Agent? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175876.aspx

Comment: I already went through above link. It nowhere provides way to configure it automatically without human intervention. That is what I want

Comment: Once you have your T-SQL built..... create it inside a scheduled SQL Agent job.

Comment: You could also use log shipping as a means to accomplish this using SQL Agent etc.

Comment: Just take a database snapshot every hour using SQL Server Agent? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms189237.aspx